# R18 manga where the main character is a zookeeper and has to breed with the human/animals hybrid in the zoo

Tags: story-identification, manga

I'm looking for an R18 manga where the main character is a zookeeper and has to breed with the animals in the zoo to keep their (the animals) populations from becoming extinct.

The animals turn into humans during the night because of the doctor's serum.

The story is pretty wholesome because we can see how close the bond between the animals and the MC is.

The MC also has a female heroine; she's like a doctor and the manager of the zoo.

The manga, as I remembered, has the two girl pandas as the cover and is already finished.

Comment: "He's having sex with the zoo animals" = *"The story is pretty wholesome"*

Answer (score 8, accepted):

This is "*[Kemokko Doubutsuen!](https://myanimelist.net/manga/110290)*".

> In order to save The Paradise Island Zoo that has lost all but the
> female animals, the Director has made it so when night falls, all the
> animals turn into cute girls! It's up to Taneda to mate with all of
> them and save the zoo!